# Parse, cloud code beforeDelete

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Before I'm deleting my user I would like to remove some objects in another class. This works fine in Swift.

```
class func deleteAnonymousUserListSettings(completetion:(result:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void){
    var queryListSettings = PFQuery(className: "ListSettings")
    queryListSettings.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let objs = objects as? [PFObject] where error == nil {
            PFObject.deleteAllInBackground(objs, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if success{
                    completetion(result: success, error: error)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to transfer this to cloudCode. It works approximately 1 out of 10 times but I don't know why or when it works and sometimes not.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query('ListSettings');
  query.find({
  success: function(results) {

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i+=1) {
        results[i].destroy();
      }
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function() {results
      response.error("error");
    }
  });
});
```

Help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, this works for me.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query('ListSettings');
    query.find().then(function(results) {

      return Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
    }).then(function() {
      response.success();

    }, function(error) {
      response.error("Error removing ListSettings.");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting one by one, you can delete all of the object at once and return success if it is successful. You can do this via the below code blocks;

```
   query.find().then(function (results) 
   {
      Parse.Object.destroyAll(results); 
      response.success("Success"); 
    }, 
    function (error) 
    {
      response.success("Error"); 
    })
```

Hope this helps.Regards.

Comment: I tried something similar before, tried yours now, the user is getting deleted with Swift and the beforeDelete is "Success". But nothing is deleted from ListSettings. The User has a pointer to ListSettings, is this something I need to take account of using Cloud Code? Thx for the help.